# Write mplayer's output to fifo and read it

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I'm trying write simple notify app in bash. I want to read output from mplayer, parse it and display through notify-send.

I can get desired info from mplayer using this:

```
mplayer <url> | grep ICY
```

and then parse in using sed.

I create named pipe, tell mplayer to write it and then I'm reading from it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Here's my script:

```
$fifo=~/.rp/fifo
mkfifo $fifo

mplayer <url> 2>/dev/null | grep ICY 1> $fifo &

while read line < $fifo; do
    echo $line
done

wait
```

Program keeps waiting to input from $fifo. I tried following in other terminal, while this script is running:

1. Run

   ```
   echo "Test" > .rp/fifo
   ```

   Terminal with running script shows "Test"
2. Run

   ```
   echo "ICY" | grep ICY > .rp/fifo
   ```

   also works.
3. Run

   ```
   mplayer <url> | grep ICY > .rp/fifo
   ```

   and it **doesn't** work.

Is I said above, the combination of mplayer | grep works fine. grep > $fifo works fine. I don't understand why mplayer | grep > $fifo doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do unbuffered grep with:

```
$ mplayer ...  2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "ICY"
```

or better:

```
$ mplayer ...  2>&1 | sed -une 's/^.*ICY[^:]*: //p'
```

or even, why not (sed is very nice for grep and formatting),
this will grep `ICY` lines and even split line containing `-` in a first field of 30 chars length separed by a `:` from a second field:

```
$ mplayer ...  2>&1 |
    sed -une "
        /ICY/{
            s/^.*ICY[^:]*:.*'\([^']*\)';/\1/;
            s/^\(.*\) - /\1                              - /;
            s/^\(.\{30\}\) *- /\1: /;
            p;
    }"
```

could give something like:

```
Artist name                  : Song title
Other artist                 : Other song
Unsplited line
Artist                       : Title
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The "--line-buffered" did the trick for me. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you might be experiencing the C library's fully buffered mode for streams. You don't say that you're running the GNU userspace, but if you are, you can look into `stdbuf(1)` to modify the buffering regime.

You might try first running just `grep` as a child of `stdbuf(1)`, like this:

```
mplayer <url> | stdbuf -o L grep ICY > .rp/fifo
```

If that doesn't work, moar is bettar!

```
stdbuf -o 0 mplayer <url> | stdbuf -o L grep ICY > .rp/fifo
```

And if that still doesn't work, then it's possible that `mplayer` isn't writing to stdout, but directly to `/dev/tty`. In which case, you will need to read up on `expect(1)`.

Comment: One stdbuf was enough. Thank you!

Comment: Using `stdbuf -o 0` is overkill regarding to `--line-buffered` option for grep or `-u` option for sed!

Answer (score 2):

I start mplayer in slave mode, using FIFO file.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mpfifo

mplayer -slave -input file=/tmp/mpfifo video.mp4
```

I am able to control the video player from another terminal.

```
echo "pause" >> /tmp/mpfifo
echo "volume 50" > /tmp/mpfifo
```

I want to get value (for example current position of playing video). So I tried:

```
echo "get_time_pos" > /tmp/mpfifo
```

But no value returned. 
I searched for hours, but no success. 
Then I thought to redirect mplayer output to a file:

```
mplayer -slave -input file=/tmp/mpfifo video.mp4 > /tmp/mpout.txt
```

After that when like following commands executed:

```
echo "get_time_pos" > /tmp/mpfifo
echo "get_property length" > /tmp/mpfifo
```

The outputs in /tmp/mpout.txt was like:

```
.......
.......
ANS_TIME_POSITION=113.6
ANS_length=2534.602031
```

If the result of each command would return to the command line would be very nice. Even it may need some works, the output file can be parsed, though.

Comment: Ah, thx! :-) Allow me to complete that already very helpful post.
`mkfifo my_pipe; mplayer -slave -idle -input file="my_pipe"`
And then in other terminal: `echo "loadfile music.mp3" >> my_pipe`. Other helpful commands are `pause` (does unpause, too) or `stop`. Good doc: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt